# Google Sheets sum of columns by matching 3 columns with one additional criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want the sum of column E by matching column A,B and C with Column G,H and I where column D is Yes (answer in column J) and blank (answer in column K). Details given in below image.

[image: Image of data]

I had tried with the below formula but its not working:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(FILTER(A3:A&B3:B&C3:C,D3:D=""),G3:G&H3:H&I3:I,FILTER(E3:E,D3:D="")))
```

The same formula is used for yes too in place of blank.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: @ TheMaster Thanks for your reply, I had tried with the below formula but its not working :=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(FILTER(A3:A&B3:B&C3:C,D3:D=""),G3:G&H3:H&I3:I,FILTER(E3:E,D3:D=""))). the same formula is used for yes too in place of blank.

Comment: Tables are copyable. Consider adding a table. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @ TheMaster thanks for your suggestion, I request you to share few more details on how to insert table, as in one post I checked that they suggested to insert image in place of sheet link so I followed the instructions of that post. Further, still I need more points to directly insert image so in my case when I enter image a link is generated in place of image.

Comment: The first link in my last comment shows how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(MAP(G3:G,H3:H,I3:I,LAMBDA(g,h,i,SUM(FILTER(E3:E,g=A3:A,h=B3:B,i=C3:C,D3:D="Yes")))),COUNTA(I:I),1)
```

`MAP` the values from `User Input`  and `FILTER` the `Data` by each value.